# Sequelize ignoring duplicates with UUID

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to ignore duplicates when doing a `bulkInsert`.

The problem is that when you are using uuid's for your primary key you must include the id in your insert statement. Because of this I generate a uuid before I insert the data and technically all the other fields could be duplicates of another row except for the uuid.

I want to know if there is a way to do an insert in Sequelize in which I can check if the row to be inserted is a duplicate dependent upon fields that I choose.

**UPDATE:** I am using the `postgres` dialect and I have just discovered that it has a `ON CONFLICT (KEY,KEY) DO NOTHING`

Answer (score 0):

As of primary keys the best way to generate them is on a DB side setting a primary key default value to `uuid_generate_v4()` (in case of PostgreSQL).
This (among other benefits) will get you an ability not to indicate a primary key column in INSERT query.

Comment: I don't define the table in SQL it's in Sequelize and even declaring that the PK is a UUIDv4 it doesn't auto-generate for some reason. I am using v5 of Sequelize, but I'm not sure if this is remedied in v6.

Comment: If you wish to generate PKs by a DBMS and not by Sequelize you should indicate `autoIncrement: true` in OK field in a model.

Comment: And set default value in a PK column by a migration